# Find the length of longest palindrome path in an undirected acyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, palindrome, undirected-graph

The problem is: given an **undirected acyclic graph *(N nodes and N-1 edges)***, where each node is labeled with a character, find the length of the longest path of nodes in the graph that forms a **palindrome**.

Suppose there are **N *(1 <= N <= 500 000)*** nodes, is there any algorithm to solve this problem with the time complexity of ***O(N^2) or O(N.log2(N))***?

After some research, I think this might be solved with Manacher Algorithm on a graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this exact problem, but with tighter constraints **(N ≤ 50 000)**, appeared on COCI 2019/2020, Round 3 (task Lampice).

here is [Tasks](https://hsin.hr/coci/archive/2019_2020/contest3_tasks.pdf) and [Editorial](https://hsin.hr/coci/archive/2019_2020/contest3_solutions.zip), it describes a solution with complexity **O(N.log2(N))**.

Comment: Nice links. It would be even better if you could briefly describe the gist of the solution in the links